Handling Nested Mouse Scroll in Swiperjs Elements
This is the Code with Vertical Swipers and have a Horizontal Swiper nested inside it in slide number 7.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Swiper demo</title>
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"
    />

    <style>
      html,
      body {
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
      }

      body {
        background: #eee;
        font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #000;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      swiper-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }

      swiper-slide {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 18px;
        background: #fff;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
      }

      swiper-slide img {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <swiper-container
      id="verticalSwiper"
      class="mySwiper"
      pagination="true"
      pagination-clickable="true"
      direction="vertical"
      space-between="30"
      mousewheel="true"
    >
      <swiper-slide>Slide 1</swiper-slide>
      <swiper-slide>Slide 2</swiper-slide>
      <swiper-slide>Slide 3</swiper-slide>
      <swiper-slide>Slide 4</swiper-slide>
      <swiper-slide>Slide 5</swiper-slide>
      <swiper-slide>Slide 6</swiper-slide>
      <swiper-slide>
        <swiper-container
          id="horizontalSwiper"
          class="mySwiper"
          pagination="true"
          pagination-clickable="true"
          direction="horizontal"
          space-between="30"
          mousewheel="true"
          mousewheelForceToAxisis="horizontal"
        >
          <swiper-slide>Slide 1</swiper-slide>
          <swiper-slide>Slide 2</swiper-slide>
          <swiper-slide>Slide 3</swiper-slide>
          <swiper-slide>Slide 4</swiper-slide>
          <swiper-slide>Slide 5</swiper-slide>
          <swiper-slide>Slide 6</swiper-slide>
          <swiper-slide>Slide 7</swiper-slide>
          <swiper-slide>Slide 8</swiper-slide>
          <swiper-slide>Slide 9</swiper-slide>
        </swiper-container>
      </swiper-slide>
      <swiper-slide>Slide 8</swiper-slide>
      <swiper-slide>Slide 9</swiper-slide>
    </swiper-container>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-element-bundle.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>


On mouse Scroll how to stop scrolling verical slider when it enter the slide that have horizontal scrolling nested in it , on the end slide of horizontal swiper , reenable the mouse scroll on vertical slider.
